# my if/else statement work properly at first and then not

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my if/else statement. it's running properly at first but when I'm changing the size of the table it's taking both conditions.
Would someone please help me fix this problem?

```
function makeGrid(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  theTable.innerHTML = "";
  var row = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
  var column = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    width = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
      height = document.createElement("td");
      width.appendChild(height);
    }
    theTable.appendChild(width);
  }
  theTable.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    colorValue = document.querySelector("#colorPicker").value;
    if (evt.target.style.backgroundColor) {
      evt.target.style.cssText = "bagckground-color: none";
      console.log("i was deleted");
    } else {
      evt.target.style.backgroundColor = colorValue;
      console.log("I was clicked");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: if you call `makeGrid` more than once in your code, you'll end up with multiple event listeners on `theTable`

Comment: Please dont check ` if (evt.target.style.backgroundColor)` either check for not empty or a specific value. The bare "if string is true" might work but its not cleancode. Additionally this can lead to type-confusion if your variables/properties are named badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you call `makeGrid` more than once in your code, you'll end up with multiple event listeners on `theTable`

So you'll need to remove the eventListener

you'll need a separate function for the event handler, not inline to be able to do this

```
function tblClick(e) {
    var colorValue = document.querySelector("#colorPicker").value;
    if (this.style.backgroundColor) {
        this.style.cssText = "bagckground-color: none";
        console.log("i was deleted");
    } else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = colorValue;
        console.log("I was clicked");
    }
}
function makeGrid(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    theTable.innerHTML = "";
    theTable.removeEventListener("click", tblClick);
    var row = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
    var column = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        width = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            height = document.createElement("td");
            width.appendChild(height);
        }
        theTable.appendChild(width);
    }
    theTable.addEventListener("click", tblClick);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was so helpful.
I really appreciate your help. Thank you!